# GDAL2Tiles has low resolution quality

Tags: qgis, gdal, openlayers, resolution, gdal2tiles

I have a project with a bunch of large, high-resolution Tiff images that I will tilling with gdal2tiles and use on Openlayers.

Those Tiff images have been taken on a drone. Example:

[image]

While I tilling this by gdal2tiles and use Openlayers to show up, the resolution is low and the quality is very bad with the same zoom level, different from my expectations.

[image]

The image layers look like blur, something makes visible mask and the detail is gone. I use gdal on OS Shell and the code is:

```
gdal2tiles -p raster --tilesize=256 abc.tif output
```

How can I improve the quality and detail of this case?

Comment: Any one can help :(

Comment: Did you try defining zoom range? Tiling benefits from serving different resolution according to the zoom ratio. When you define zoom option for gdal2tiles, the second number is for max zoom, you should keep it big like 20.